# Función de sublime tex 3 para atom?

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

quiero saber si se puede agregarle una función que tiene Sublime Text 3 a Atom, la cual es de seleccionar una palabra y el editor me muestra las que coinciden.

**Sublime Text 3:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ATOM:**(no la tiene)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: No agregues tu código como imagen, agrégalo como texto y utiliza la herramienta del editor para darle formato de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando rapidamente en google encontre esto espero y te sirva

https://atom.io/packages/selection-highlight

Comment: Gracias :D por tu aporte si me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

La función de mostrar similares debes aplicarlo con un repo. El que actualmente utilizo y funciona muy bien es [Highlight Selected](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected), que sería un proyecto extendido de buscar y reemplazar.

Comment: Gracias :D por tu aporte